# Non-uniqueness of closest point in a closed, convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, reflexive-space

I have seen that if $X$ is a Hilbert space and $K$ is some non-empty, closed, convex subset then for every $x \in X $ there exists a  unique $y \in K$ which is closer to any other point of $K$. However, I wanted to see when uniqueness does not hold when making the weaker assumption that X is *reflexive*. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mathbb R^2$, with the norm $\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert_1=\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert$. Then the line segment $K$ going from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ is non-empty, closed and convex.  However, each element of $K$ is at distance $1$ from $(0,0)$.

Comment: ah yea I didn't think about putting a non-canonical norm on an otherwise Hilbert space. Thanks